# WebClient timing out after .DownloadString

Tags: .net, vb.net, webclient

I'm trying to grab the source code of a website. The website I'm linking to is just a .txt file, the HTML of the website has no HTML tags and is plain text.

When I try to download the source upon Form1_Load it retrieves the source fine, when I try to "refresh" and re-download the source it works fine. However, when I try to "refresh" the website for the second (third time including Form1_Load) the WebClient times out.

```
    Try
        Dim wClient_getSourceRefresh As WebClient = New WebClient
        Dim allMessages As String = wClient_getSourceRefresh.DownloadString("http://example.com/example.txt")
        wClient_getSourceRefresh.Dispose()
        TextBox2.Text = allMessages
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Does anyone know why the client is timing out and how I can fix this?

Comment: You can consistently reproduce, that it times out the third time you try it every time you start the application? Are you sure it wasn't just a connectivity issue, i.e. it actually timed out trying to download the URL?

Comment: Yeah, it times out downloading the source code. But the website is perfectly accessible.

Comment: Can you consistently reproduce it (the third time) or even post a complete sample reproducing it?

Comment: What do you mean reproduce it?

Comment: Does the error happen to you consistently or only occasionally? It would be best if one could run your code directly and receive the same error.

Comment: It happens every time, I'll try running the application on another computer. The problem is, it only happens on the third time of retrieving the source.

Comment: It probably doesn't happen if you create a completely new project with a single form and the only code in it downloading the source of e.g. `http://www.google.com` in `Form_Load` and on `Refresh_Click`? Start from there and try determining what starts causing the error. Or create a sample project demonstrating this behavior.

Comment: Well currently the only code I literally have is the Refresh code - apart from that I've got a button which writes to the text file on the website (it writes to the text file it's reading from)

Comment: Public website or a private one of your own? Try the refresh code with a different URL / site.

Comment: I don't host the website, it's just basically a free hosting I use to keep track of some statistics.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46596/discussion-between-damir-arh-and-user3102516)